# Please indicate the preferred endpoint configuration section by name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, web-config

***Before some one commenting that it is a duplicate***,  please note that i have gone through the suggestions given  in internet.

**Scenario:**

I  am having a web api call and have only one end point  in the webconfig`

```
 <client>
           <endpoint address="http://localhost/RegistrationService/RegistrationService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RegistrationService"
        contract="RegistrationService.IRegistrationService" name="RegistrationService" />
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/ElectronicCustomerFileService/ElectronicCustomerFileService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ElectronicCustomerFileService"
        contract="ElectronicCustomerFileService.IElectronicCustomerFileService"
        name="ElectronicCustomerFileService" />
    </client>
```

`

following is the binding equivalent

`

```
 <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="RegistrationService" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="ElectronicCustomerFileService" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

`

While i run the application i am getting error

> An endpoint configuration section for contract 'ElectronicCustomerFileService.IElectronicCustomerFileService' could not be loaded because more than one endpoint configuration for that contract was found. Please indicate the preferred endpoint configuration section by name.

**Tools Used**

I am using Visual studio 2017 . I had  Visual Studio 2019 and uninstalled it thinking that the issue is due to visual studio version issue

**Interesting Fact**

If i  remove the end point from the webconfig , and try connecting to the web api, it is working properly .  I checked the folder to see if any other webconfig is there in root folder and cannot find it

From where this web config is getting  called

I restarted  IIS.  Deleted temporary files in Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files. But not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the default website directory was pointing to a different project location 
Go to IIS manager [image]

- Select  Default Web site 
  [image]
- go to basic setting in  right hand side
  [image]

  - Check if the Physical path is pointing to a different location

[image]

- If the path is not pointing to  above,  change the physical path to

> %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot

[image]